# Trying to access Libraries folder with cygwin

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, path

I saved some files in

```
Libraries -> Documents
```

on windows 7 and I try to access to those files with cygwin.

Where is that folder `Documents` ?

I've looked under `/cygdrive/c/Users/my_user/` but I don't find my files.

[image: Libraries -> Documents]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the local "Documents" library is actually the combination of two folders - a private folder for the user and a public folder for all users on the computer. Try the following Cygwin folder paths for a hypothetical user "jdoe".

- /cygdrive/c/Users/Public/Documents
- /cygdrive/c/Users/jdoe/Documents

If you look in both locations, you should find all items visible in your "Documents" library. If your network policy is using document redirection, or other remote document folder techniques, then the user folder may be on a remote machine - sounds like you're using a default local folder setup though.

If for some reason your personal "Documents" path is not the default, it will be revealed by the following command. Even though this is a Windows command, it will work in the Cygwin shell.

```
reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "Personal"
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that you could query the registry from cygwin.

Comment: I found my files into `/cygdrive/c/Users/Public/Documents`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky, because it's hidden in the AppData but the actual "real" path is:

```
C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms
```

And the path of the `Library`only is of course:

```
C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\
```

Comment: It's a XML file, not a folder. The folder `Libraries` contains `desktop.ini`,  `Documents.library-ms`, `Music.library-ms`,  `Pictures.library-ms` and  `Videos.library-ms`